# Azure Storage - NodeJS - Can I Store Objects?

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-table-storage

[The Azure Storage library for NodeJS](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-node) shows creating a Task as follows:

```
var azure = require('azure-storage');
var entGen = azure.TableUtilities.entityGenerator;
var task = {
  PartitionKey: entGen.String('hometasks'),
  RowKey: entGen.String('1'),
  description: entGen.String('take out the trash'),
  dueDate: entGen.DateTime(new Date(Date.UTC(2015, 6, 20))),
};
```

But is it possible to store an object (e.g. Like Stuff):

```
var azure = require('azure-storage');
var entGen = azure.TableUtilities.entityGenerator;
var task = {
  PartitionKey: entGen.String('hometasks'),
  RowKey: entGen.String('1'),
  description: entGen.String('take out the trash'),
  dueDate: entGen.DateTime(new Date(Date.UTC(2015, 6, 20))),
  stuff : { "abc" : "def", "ghi" : "jkl", "mno" : { "pqr" : "stf" }}
};
```

Or do I need to JSON.stringify it and store it as a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, `stuff` is JSON. Table Storage entities don't have a `JSON` type. You'd need to stringify, resulting in a `String` type.

You could also choose to use separate properties for each element in your JSON doc (and every entity could contain different properties - no schema is enforced; you'd just need to give yourself a hint on stored object type, so that you could retrieve the properties as needed). And yes, that gets trickier as you continue to nest JSON objects, as your example does.

FYI all supported Table entity types are listed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/understanding-the-table-service-data-model).

Comment: On the second item are you saying I can do:
stuff : { "abc" : entGen.String("def"), "ghi" : { "aaa" : entGen.String("w") } }

or are you simply saying I could move them all up to the top level, realizing that every entity won't have the same properties?

Comment: I'm saying you either stringify the entire JSON or you store each JSON property as a separate Table entity string property. There is no JSON property type.